# C++: How to use type in template function to branch?

Tags: c++, template-function

I am not quite proficient with templates. How do I write the a template function called get that chooses the array it gets from based on the template type? See the example below:

```
struct Foo
{
    int iArr[10];
    char cArr[10];

    // How to pick array here based on template type?
    template < typename T >
    T get( int idx )
    {
        // This does NOT work!
        switch ( T )
        {
        case int:
            return iArr[ idx ];
        case char:
            return cArr[ idx ];
        }
    }
};

// Expected behaviour of get()
Foo foo;
int i  = foo.get< int >( 2 );
char c = foo.get< char >( 4 );
```

Comment: The way you wrote it that's not possible, since there's nothing "generic" about your code. You just want a selector for two members. You can just use ordinary class design for that. For something truly generic you could try boost.variant.

Comment: Kerrek: This is just a simple example. In my actual program, I have many more type specific arrays. I do not want to write separate functions for all of them.

Comment: Do all those arrays have to be members of your class? That would be tricky because classes must be definite, but if you only have a bounded amount of containers, I have a feeling that templates aren't really the right domain for the problem here.

Comment: Consider tinkering with this: `template <typename T> struct helper { T arr[10]; T get(std::size_t i) { return arr[i]; } }; struct foo : public helper<int>, public helper<char> {};`

Answer (score 11):

While the solution proposed by Jason works, it's far from idiomatic, and is harder to maintain since the `case` values in the `switch` statement 1) have no apparent meaning ("magic numbers") and 2) could easily get out of sync with the values in the `switch_value<>` specializations. I would propose this instead:

```cpp
struct Foo {
    Foo() : iArr(), cArr() { }

    template<typename T>
    T get(std::size_t const idx) const     {
        return Foo::get_dispatcher<T>::impl(*this, idx);
    }

private:
    int iArr[10];
    char cArr[10];

    template<typename T>
    struct get_dispatcher;
};

template<>
struct Foo::get_dispatcher<int> {
    static int impl(Foo const& foo, std::size_t const idx) {
        return foo.iArr[idx];
    }
};

template<>
struct Foo::get_dispatcher<char> {
    static char impl(Foo const& foo, std::size_t const idx) {
        return foo.cArr[idx];
    }
};
```

Invoking `Foo::get<>` with any type other than `int` or `char` will yield a compiler error.

Answer (score 9):

You would need to add a value structure of some type you can use to get the values for your switch-statement from.  For instance:

```
template<typename T>
struct switch_value {};

template<>
struct switch_value<int>
{
    enum { value = 1 };
};

template<>
struct switch_value<char>
{
    enum { value = 2 };
};

//then inside you structure Foo
template <typename T>
T get( int idx )
{
    switch ( switch_value<T>::value )
    {
    case 1:
        return iArr[ idx ];
    case 2:
        return cArr[ idx ];
    }
}
```

The nice thing here is this should throw a compiler error if you use a type that does not have a valid value since the default version of `switch_value<T>` does not define a member `value`, so if you haven't specialized the structure for a specific type, then such a template instantiation will fail.

Comment: Jason: Thanks so much! This works perfectly for my problem. Unless someone gives a more elegant solution, yours is the solution :-)

Comment: Would the compiler optimize that code away, instead of ending with a switch in the final code, ending with a function that does only the case for each generation of functions with that template ?

Answer (score 3):

All of these answers are wayyyy overkill.

```
template <typename T>
T get( int idx )
{
   if ( boost::is_same<T, int>::value)
      return *(T*)&iArr[ idx ];
   else
      return *(T*)&cArr[ idx ];
}
```

Comment: This won't work if `T` can be a class type, e.g. `std::list<>`.

Comment: `is_same` is also in the [C++ standard library](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_same)

Answer (score 1):

You could specialise the member function:

```
struct foo
{
    int  iArr[10];
    char cArr[10];

    template<typename T>
    T &get(int ipos) { assert( false && "Foo.get: Invalid type!" ); return T(); }

    template<>
    int &get<int>(int ipos) { return iArr[ipos]; }

    template<> 
    char &get<char>(int ipos) {return cArr[ipos]; }

    // add more specialisations for any other types...
};
```

Works with msvc++ 2010. Hope this helps.

The switch specialisation suggested by Jason should also work fine.

Comment: This is not legal C++; MSVC allows it as a silent extension, but any other compiler will choke.

Answer (score 1):

This is probably overkill for your example, but if you really only need to store one array at a time, then you can use the boost::variant class and a visitor, e.g.,

```
#include <boost/variant.hpp>
#include <iostream>

template< typename T >
class GetVisitor : public boost::static_visitor<T>
{
  public:
    GetVisitor(int index) : index_(index) {};

    template <typename U >
    T operator() (U const& vOperand) const
    {
        return vOperand[index_];
    }

  private:
    int index_;
};


int main ()
{
    int  iArr[10] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 };
    char cArr[10] = { 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j' };

    boost::variant<int*, char*>  intVariant(iArr);   //- assign integer array to variant
    boost::variant<int*, char*>  charVariant(cArr);  //- assign character array to another variant

    int  testInt  = boost::apply_visitor(GetVisitor<int>(2),  intVariant);  
    char testChar = boost::apply_visitor(GetVisitor<char>(9), charVariant);

    std::cout << "returned integer is "   << testInt  << std::endl;
    std::cout << "returned character is " << testChar << std::endl;

    return 0;
}

output is:   
returned integer is 3   
returned character is j
```

The restriction on the variant implied by the GetVisitor class is that all members of the variant must implement:

```
T operator[](int)
```

So you could also add, e.g., std::vector and std::deque as potential members of the variant.

Answer (score 0):

I assume this is what you want beside just focusing on template function:

in a .h file

```
template < typename T >
struct Foo
{
    T arr[10];

    T get( int idx )
    {
      return arr[ idx ];
    }
};
```

somewhere you use it like:

```
Foo<int> foo1;
Foo<char> foo2;
int i  = foo1.get( 2 );
char c = foo2.get( 4 );
```